# jQuery button to filter HTML table based on classes assigned to table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck on a problem with my code and have been reading suggestions and code and although I have come close I have not managed to get what I am looking for.

**Background:**
I have an HTML page that I been working on for the last week or so and I have managed to get a lot of cool stuff done with it. (A search bar which searches based on text that i input, a table sorter to sort my table rows when I click the table headers and some pretty cool formatting with CSS.)

**What I want to add:**
So I have managed to do all the cool stuff above, now I want to add some buttons to the HTML page above the Table Header which will do the following. When I click one of the buttons I want my table to only display table rows which match some predefined classes. Will go into more detail below. (Buttons can be radio buttons or just regular buttons - Does not matter.)

**What I have tried:**
I have tried all kinds of snippets of code and I have had some success. I was able at one point to filter the table rows according the the classes by pressing a button. Small problem is it would hide the table header and I could not get it to display all the rows again. (FML right?)

**Reduced version of my code thus far:**
I have stripped out quite a bit of the irrelevant stuff.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/styles.css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="__jquery.tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="__jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="lib/w3.js"></script>
// call the tablesorter plugin
<script type="text/javascript" id="js">$(document).ready(function() {

    $("table").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[0,0],[0,0]]
    });
}); </script>


</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th >PasswordExpired</th><th>DaysRemaining</th><th>Roaming</th><th>Exempt</th><th>Violation</th><th>Note</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>47</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
<tr class="Exempt"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>N/A</td><td>False</td><td>True</td><td>False</td><td>The password of this account never expires</td></tr>
<tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>44</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
<tr class="Soon"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>3</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Imminent Expiration. Mail Sent</td></tr>
<tr class="Inactive"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>True</td><td>N/A</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>This account has not logged into the domain in more than 90 days.</td></tr>
<tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>53</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
<tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>aemail@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>51</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
<tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>88</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
<tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>53</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>

</tbody>
          </table>
          </body>
          </html>
```

**A little more explanation:**
So what I would like to be able to do is have a few buttons that I can click that will filter my table rows according to the listed classes (Healthy/Exempt/Soon/Inactive).

**Conclusion:**
HTML and CSS I was able to pick up rather quickly and should be able to adapt any code you can suggest. Could anyone provide some code that is easy to understand and easy to adapt?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind another/a new plugin, I'd suggest reading up about "DataTables". I've been using that over anything else and am very happy with it. It provides filtering, sorting, functions/events for each of those and much much more.

Comment: investigate the jQuery selector page https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ You'll learn by doing :) Then check out the jQuery .show(), .hide() and .toggle() functions, e.g.: `$(".myClass").hide();` Remember you may want to show all `$("tr").show()` before hiding one class.

Comment: @N.M.

Thanks for the advise. Hoping to try and avoid more plugins. Would prefer to learn how to do it myself so I can implement it in future projects. But as a worse can scenario I will look into the recommended plugin.

Comment: @gordon - Thanks gordon, did some reading up on your suggestions and they did help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, explanation in comments:
(Please note that the code can be optimized better, I will update a optimized version soon).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/styles.css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="__jquery.tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="__jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/w3.js"></script>
        // call the tablesorter plugin
        <script type="text/javascript" id="js">
             var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
             console.dir(tableRows);
             //get all the elements inside tr tag
             //eventListeners are added to the buttons inside the script tag in body
             //See the script in the body tag   
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
              <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
                  <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Name</th>
                           <th>Username</th>
                           <th>PasswordExpired</th>
                           <th>DaysRemaining</th>
                           <th>Roaming</th>
                           <th>Exempt</th>
                           <th>Violation</th>
                           <th>Note</th>
                       </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                        <tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>47</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Exempt"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>N/A</td><td>False</td><td>True</td><td>False</td><td>The password of this account never expires</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>44</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Soon"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>3</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Imminent Expiration. Mail Sent</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Inactive"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>True</td><td>N/A</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>This account has not logged into the domain in more than 90 days.</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>53</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>aemail@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>51</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>88</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
                        <tr class="Healthy"><td>Username</td><td>email@comapny.com</td><td>False</td><td>53</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>False</td><td>Healthy Password Status</td></tr>
               </tbody>
         </table>
         <br/>
         <button id="Healthy">Only Healthy</button>
         <br/>
         <button id="Soon">Only Soon</button>
         <br/>
         <button id="Inactive">Only Inactive</button>
         <br/>
         <button id="Exempt">Only Exempt</button>
         <br/>
         <button id="all">Show All</button>
         <br/>
      <script>
            //get all buttons
            var healthy = document.getElementById('Healthy');
            console.log(healthy);
            var soon = document.getElementById('Soon');
            var inactive = document.getElementById('Inactive');
            var exempt = document.getElementById('Exempt');
            var all = document.getElementById('all');

            //check if the class exists for each of the tr element
            healthy.addEventListener('click', function() {
                for(var i=1; i<tableRows.length; i++) { //loop starts with 1 and not 0 because first element is th
                    if(tableRows[i].className !== 'Healthy') {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = true; //hide other than Healthy
                    } else {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = false; //display only Healthy
                    }
                }
            });

            soon.addEventListener('click', function() {
                for(var i=1; i<tableRows.length; i++) {
                    if(tableRows[i].className !== 'Soon') {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = true;
                    } else {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = false;
                    }
                }
            });

            inactive.addEventListener('click', function() {
                for(var i=1; i<tableRows.length; i++) {
                    if(tableRows[i].className !== 'Inactive') {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = true;
                    } else {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = false;
                    }
                }
            });

            exempt.addEventListener('click', function() {
                for(var i=1; i<tableRows.length; i++) {
                    if(tableRows[i].className !== 'Exempt') {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = true;
                    } else {
                        tableRows[i].hidden = false;
                    }
                }
            });

            all.addEventListener('click', function() {
                for(var i=1; i<tableRows.length; i++) {
                    tableRows[i].hidden = false;
                }
            });


      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

I have posted this redudant and details version for your understanding, let me know if you need more explanation or any additions.

JQuery equivalents of the javascript used in the answer:

```
  getElementsByTagName => $("tagnamehere") 
  for loop => for(i = 0; i < $("tagnamehere").length; i++) {}
  getElementById => $("#idhere")
  all.addEventListener('click', function() {}) => $("#all").bind("click", function() {})
  tableRows[i].hidden = true  => tableRows[i].hide();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I dumped it straight into the code and it did not work off the bat. But no problem, going to play around with it. The logic seems pretty solid. Have a solid framework to play with now.

Comment: It should work as file, I am sure it does. But I have also left room for you to play around in jquery. Please select this answer as correct (the tick mark), if it helped you and upvote. And, you are welcome!

Comment: Hmm I created a new file and you are right it works just fine. Time to get my reverse engineering hat on. :D Thanks again Harman!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Found out why it was not working.
I did not add the call script in the body to my original code. *DOH!*

I also had another very small table in the original code, the buttons would sort this table as well. This was however circumvent by increasing the starting integer in each of the newly created variables.

So in short, everything is working exactly how I was hoping it would. Thank you very very much for your assistance.

Time to make those buttons look sexy with some CSS. :D

Comment: Haha, you can use bootstrap or some framework and it's sexy buttons. Also, a little about optimization part of the code: you can create an array of those buttons and define one function as it is repititive, and call it everytime you need.

Comment: Wow thanks for the tips regarding optimization. The test sample only has a few table rows. The real thing will keep growing. I remember from my early attempts at table sorting that an array is a must. I might just end up sending you a message if I get stuck. But that will only be after I have run out of rocks to look under. ;D

Comment: Not a problem, yeah never stop exploring